# Show result including a specific string in the result of 'pyenv install --list' result in WSL

Tags: ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 using WSL2 in Windows 11.

The command 'pyenv install --list' shows a list of available Python versions.

[image]

Here I want to see only Python 3.9 such as

```
3.9.9
3.9.10
pypy3.9-7.3.9
```

etc.
So I want to filter the result so that only the versions including the string '3.9' are shown.

How can I do this?

What I tried is using

```
pyenv install --list > result.txt
```

and processing this result.txt file in Python using regular expression. But this is too lengthy, so I think there is simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "grep"

```bash
pyenv install --list | grep 3.9
```